# Update UIAlertView message after/during show in iOS7

Tags: ios7, uialertview

I want to show a UIAlertView with a message and I need to update it's message during show of alert.
I use following code:

```
UIAlertView alert = [UIAlertView new];
[alert setMessage:@"Blah blah"];
[alert show];
```

and I want it to be updated in a NSTimer update method:

```
[alert setMessage:@"Blah blah ..."];
```

Above code just worked fine in iOS6/5! 
But it doesn't work in iOS7.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: I want it to be updated every 1 second!

Answer (score 0):

Add `UIAlertViewDelegate` in your interface file.

And add the following method in your implementation file.

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    alertView.message = @"Message to be changed";
}
```

**Edit**

Implement the following code where you want to display the alert:

```
NSTimer *countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60.0 target: self selector: @selector(alertForEveryOneMinute) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

Then implement the `alertForEveryOneMinute` method in your implementation file and display your alert from that method.